# Filter and sort array of objects

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of objects

```
const a = [
  { name: 'z', items: [..] },
  { name: 'x', items: [..] },
  { name: 'y', items: [..] },
  { name: 'a', items: [..] },
]
```

I would like to select and reorder such that I transform the array into

```
const a_new = [
  { name: 'x', items: [..] },
  { name: 'y', items: [..] },
  { name: 'z', items: [..] },
]
```

i.e. I only want those with name `x`, `y`, and `z` and I want it ordered by some specific order (not just alphanumerically).

So I would like to, for instance, specify an array `['x', 'y', 'z']`, indicating which names I would allow and how they should be sorted.

Could it be something like

```
['x', 'y', 'z'].map(allowedValue => a.find(b => b.name === allowedValue))
```

It just seems a bit memory heavy?

Comment: Why not call `filter` and `sort` as indicated by your title?

Comment: What is issue with `['x', 'y', 'z'].map(allowedValue => a.find(b => b.name === allowedValue))`? What do you mean by "memory heavy"?

Comment: You could `reduce` `a` to a “hash map” object where the keys are the values of the `name` property of each object, then map `["x", "y", "z"]` to the objects that you can look up from the hash map. This should yield a time complexity of O(n), but the space complexity would be worse.

Comment: Ultimate answer really depends on size of data sets

Answer (score 2):

You could build a Map out of a:

```
const byName = new Map(a.map( obj => [obj.name, obj]));
```

So now we can easily get the result in O(n):

```
 const result = ['x', 'y', 'z'].map(name => byName.get(name));
```

This should be faster than your solution, however its memory consumption is much higher.

Comment: Unfortunately it's even slower than the filter&sort solution.

Comment: @Kinduser I doubt that… for larger inputs, this solution _should_ be faster.

Comment: @kind user i think O(2n) is faster than O(n * log n) or am i wrong?

Comment: Just tested it on two different benchmarks and yeah, it is slower. I'm not saying that it's wrong, just lil bit slower then the other solutions. However, tested it on the same array as OP provided.

Comment: But... why? How can you be so sure that OP going to handle arrays of 1000+ size?

Comment: @kind user well i dont know. But honestly the OP found the best solution concerning memory usage already, ive added a more performant version ( if you specify that real arrays have more than 3 elements)

Comment: @Kinduser - if the data set is small, the difference in speed would be negligible anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could firstly filter specified elements with `Array#filter` and then sort it according to index of given element inside the `b` (schema) array.

```js
const a = [
  { name: 'z', items: [] },
  { name: 'x', items: [] },
  { name: 'y', items: [] },
  { name: 'a', items: [] },
];

const b = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

const c = a.filter(({ name }) => b.includes(name))
           .sort(({ name: r }, { name: t }) => b.indexOf(r) - b.indexOf(t));
           
console.log(c);
```

Comment: @Xufox He asked for a sorting solution (he tagged `sorting` keyword aswell) so here it is.

Comment: No, he asked whether the code he already showed was good enough and used little enough memory. He was not asking for a sorting solution.

Comment: @Xufox I got a different opinion, however I'm pretty curious if it will be faster than his actual solution. Going to test it now.

Comment: I would bet it is faster since `find()` has to do a  lot of iterations

Comment: @charlietfl Doesn’t `includes` have the same problem as `find`?

Comment: @Xufox yes...but am assuming the allowable array will be considerably smaller. Your hashmap suggestion would defintiely be more performant

Comment: @charlietfl Just tested it and seems like OP's solution is slightly faster

Comment: Based on what array sizes though? A hashmap solution would beat both I am sure of that

Comment: @charlietfl Exactly the same as he provided in the question, should I exceed/raise it's size?

Comment: Not sure...Op would need to chime in on that part. If both are small differences might be irrelevant...if haystack is large and needles are small yours would probably be better